# Targeting child by index using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to modify the content of a particular column of a table whenever a cell is modified. The column is the one with the cell being modified in it.

Finding the index of the cell being modified in a particular row was quite straightforward. I found the table row and indexed it for the action.

But now I want to use that index to modify the column, including the trigger cell.

```
var childIndex = $this.closest('td').index(); // find index of trigger cell
var $allTableRows = $('tr'); // select all rows to index the particular cell
var aim = $allTableRows.children(childIndex); //search for target column here
```

I am making some mistake in passing the **childIndex** to the **row-child** criteria. 
Can someone please point out my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm don't fully understand what you are trying to do here but it kind of looks like you could do it much easier. Can you explain better or post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, I am creating a table whose rows & columns are supposed to be resizable. That is, if you change the height of one cell then the height of the entire row will be changed, and if you change the width of a cell, then the width of the entire column is changed. Have got the row part working, but am stuck here on the column part.

Comment: Could'nt you just do that with CSS `border-collapse` and `table-layout` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you use the following you'll get what you want:

```
var targetColumnInAllRows = $('tr td:nth-child(' + (childIndex + 1) + ')');
```

Note that while the index is zero-based, `nth-child` is one-based.